# Optimization of OpenCL code?

Tags: opencl

I have a code in OpenCL that adds elements of an array in steps of 4 decrementing from a given point.

This is the code - `rp` is the source array and `out` is the output array):

```
__kernel void subFilter(__global unsigned char* rp,__global unsigned char *out,int istop,int bpp)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);//add the offset by bpp to access the next gid
    int i;
    unsigned char temp=0;

    if(gid>=bpp){
         i=gid;
        while(i>=0)
        {
            if((temp + rp[i])>255)
            {
                temp = temp - 256;
                temp=temp + rp[i];
            }
            else
            {
                temp=temp+rp[i];
            }
            i=i-bpp;
        }
        out[gid]=(temp & 0xff);  //masked
        //rp[gid]=66;
    }
    else if(gid<bpp)
    out[gid]=rp[gid];
}
```

Now this is working fine but taking more time than same code run on a CPU. Perhaps it would be faster if the loop were removed?
When executed, it works like this:

```
rp[0] = rp[0];        // same for rp[1],rp[2],rp[3]
rp[4] = rp[4]+rp[4-4] // steps of 4 till zero
// ...
rp[16]= rp[16]+rp[12]+rp[8]+rp[4]+rp[0]; // etc.
```

The resulting `rp[i]` is saved in temp in the code and finally in `out[gid]`.
So, to add this sequence the loop is required and it takes lots of time...
If there is some way, that the previous sums can be cached or the loop can be removed entirely, that would be great.

How can I improve this code to get rid of the loop?

Comment: Aside from the formatting, there are a number of syntax errors in the kernel. Please post a working version of your code. If it is correctly indented in an external editor, you can copy-paste it into the question, select it all and do `ctrl-k` (or click the "code sample" button). This should retain the indentation.

Comment: this is the actual working kernel..updated in the question

Comment: Where is `i` initialised?

Comment: sorry, while removing a comment, that got removed too, I have it corrected now.

Comment: I've made some changes to your wording, feel free to undo them or make further modifications.

Comment: Could the if/else inside the loop be replace with the single statement "temp+=rp[i];"?

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to get rid of possible uchar overflows:

```
__kernel void subFilter(
    __global unsigned char  *rp,
    __global unsigned char  *out,
    int                     istop,
    int                     bpp)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0), i = gid;
    unsigned char temp = 0;

    if(gid>=bpp){
        i=gid;

        while(i>=0)
        {
            if(temp > 255 - rp[i])
            {
                temp -= 255 - rp[i];
            }
            else
            {
                temp += rp[i];
            }

            i -= bpp;
        }

        //masked
        out[gid]=(temp & 0xff);  
    }
    else if(gid<bpp){
        out[gid]=rp[gid];
    }
}
```

Coming back to filtering algorithm. Every Work Item has it's unique ID, which is used as loop counter. Generally, that's bad, because different set of instructions is applied to same data, which violates SIMD ideology. Possibly, this leads to threads divergence & performance drops. What is the nature of your algorithm? Describe it in details. May be, GPU-amenable implementation exists.

Comment: The C language rule of integer promotion prevents "possible uchar overflows" in the original code.

Comment: I mean that variables will be in uchar value range & no conversions to bigger types will be done.

Comment: My algo tries to decode a PNG image, and this part implements the sub filter. This simply adds the current pixel with the previous pixel. bpp defines the bytes taken by each pixel, and each component (R,G,B) is added to the corresponding part. In sequential  code, the values are added and updated at the current place as I said, eg:- if i=4; then rp[i]=rp[4]+rp[0], for the next iteration when i=8; rp[8]=rp[8]+rp[4] as rp[4] is already updated which not the case in parallel execution. In parallel,I have to calculate that value every time for every work item.eg:- rp[8]=rp[8]+rp[4]+rp[0]....

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the conditional code inside the loop might improve performance:

```
__kernel void subFilter(__global unsigned char* rp,__global unsigned char *out,int istop,int bpp)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);//add the offset by bpp to access the next gid
    int i;
    unsigned char temp=0;

    out[gid]=rp[gid];
    if(gid>=bpp){
        i=gid;
        while(i>=0)
        {
            temp+=rp[i];
            i-=bpp;
        }
        out[gid]=(temp & 0xff);  //masked
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the overflow be handled properly? I would put a int32 as temp value just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @DarkZeros, if a test wrapper I used is generating good coverage then this version is equivalent to the original. On the other hand, use of int32 as you suggest would most likely improve performance and reduce code size: http://notabs.org/coding/smallIntsBigPenalty.htm.

Comment: int32 is not working
this is the error by putting int32
error -45 in clCreateKernel sub
error -48 in clsetkernelargs 1
error -48 in clsetkernelargs 2
Error -48 in clsetkernelargs 3
error -48 in clsetkernelargs 4
error -48 in NDRANge